# MySQL client that can not connect to a database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to write a MySQL client in c# to acces a MySQl remote server to get some data and I keep getting this error:

```
host 192.168.2.1 is not allowed to connect to this mysql server
```

and I found a solution :

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.2.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This means that for every IP I should do the same?

I'm will use this in a game so isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use `%` for all IPs.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password';
```

You should consider creating/using other user than `root`. May be create one specific to your application with access limited to a particular database.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not have root@'%' user. Except that, you can use % as a wildcard character in hosts.

If you want all hosts, use 'user'@'%', if you want all hosts begining with host1 use 'user'@'host1-%', etc.